# React router route's match.params isn't showing the "new" value when going back in history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Well taking the following component:

```
export const OrganizationEventSelector = 
        inject('organizationStore', 'routingStore')(observer(class EventSelector extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    gotoPreviousTab = () => {
        const {routingStore} = this.props;
        routingStore.goBack();
    };

    render() {
        const {classes, onEnrollEvents, match} = this.props;
        console.log(match.params[0]);
        const remainingPath = match.params[0] || "";
        const idx =  remainingPath ? 1 : 0;

        return (<>
            <div>
                <Toolbar disableGutters={true}>
                    {idx > 0 &&
                        <div>
                            <IconButton onClick={this.gotoPreviousTab}>
                                <ChevronLeftIcon />
                            </IconButton>
                        </div>
                    }
                    <Typography >
                        {idx === 0 ? "Organizations" : "Details"}
                    </Typography>
                </Toolbar>
            </div>
        </>);
    }
}));
```

This component lives in a route:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path={['/', '/home']} exact component={HomeView}/>
    <Route path={['/organizations']} exact component={OrganizationEventSelector}/>
    <Route path={['/organizations/*']} component={OrganizationEventSelector}/>
</Switch>
```

Now when going to the url `SITE/organizations` it correctly shows the 'Organizations' title. And if I go to the next page (button, which is in another component) the url becomes `SITE/organizations/org-0` and it correctly displays the 'back icon' and "Details".

However if I then click on the `IconButton` the url  *is* updated (to `SITE/organizations`), and adding breakpoints/console logs shows that the render function is called.

However during rendering the match.params[0] = `org-0`. As if the url didn't update, even worse: match.url is actually still `SITE/organizations/org-0`.

So why does this happen? And how do I make my components rerender after the url has updated (or let them know the new url).

EDIT:
I notice the site does work in firefox. It is "just" in chrome that it isn't working.